# I can't raise any levies at all, is that a bug?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I was playing as a king (Austrasia), then I was overthrown. I am now Duke of Brabant. The year is 913, I started in 769.

However, I can't raise any of my demesne or liege levies. All of the buttons to raise them are grey, even though my army isn't already raised. I can still declare war on people.

Is this a bug or is there a particular reason for this behavior that the game is not specifying?

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: I don't play CK, so I don't know enough to say it's a duplicate, but do any of the answers to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93570/why-cant-i-raise-levies-from-half-of-my-counties) help at all?

Comment: @pushasha : No, this is a different problem.

Comment: @Philipp : My vassals are not tribal rulers. In addition, I can't raise my own army, which should be possible even with tribal vassals.

Comment: Are your demense and vassal areas occupied by foreign troops?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but no, I don't think my land was occupied.